# GWT remote server debugging.. Its painfully slow on every browser refresh

Tags: gwt, remote-debugging

I am using GWT 2.5.0 and in my server side code there are several datasources so i am not able to run embedded jetty server. 
So, I am resolved to use gwt debugger with -noserver option. Now i am able to debug my application but every time i refresh my browser, it takes hell lot of time to load application on browser and also it is very resource consuming.

On my eclipse, i can see through log message on console that every time i refresh, it recompiles all the RPC classes and verify.This process takes a lot of time.

My question is that it should happen only for the first time app gets loaded on browser not on every refresh. Is there any way, to get rid of this. It really takes lot of my time.
Looking forward for the help,
regards,
pankaj

Answer (score 1):

We use [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/). It spared us months of redeployment efforts. I consider it much better than GWT super dev mode.